# php - form include image upload

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax

I try to make a form to include image upload. let say I have table `participant` which I would like to insert to:

```
INSERT INTO `participant`(`Matric`, `Name`, `IC`, `Address`, `Tel`, `Phone`, 
`Email`, `Phone_Ref`, `Institute`, `Course`, `Pic_Participant`, `Exp_Work`) 
VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6],[value-7],
[value-8],[value-9],[value-10],[value-11],[value-12])
```

What I want to do is to insert data and upload an image. Its attribute which is `Pic_Participant`.

I search about upload using ajax [Ajax Image Upload and Resize with jQuery and PHP](http://www.saaraan.com/2012/05/ajax-image-upload-and-resize-with-jquery-and-php) . Then I think the flow, fill the form then upload image in same page, then after upload image the data for image send to db, but the form does not submit yet. How can I get attribute from table image to add in table participant?

Please help me. I'm new about this.

---

> EDIT

i try this code but get an error: Undefined variable

```
 <?php

session_start();

include 'dbconnect.php';

function is_valid_type($file)
{
$valid_types = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/bmp", "image/gif");

if (in_array($file['type'], $valid_types))
return 1;
return 0;
}


function showContents($array)
{
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
}


$TARGET_PATH = "upload/";

//ERROR START HERE

$Matric = $_POST['Matric'];
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$IC = $_POST['IC'];
$Address = $_POST['Address'];
$Tel = $_POST['Tel'];
$Phone = $_POST['Phone'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Phone_Ref = $_POST['Phone_Ref'];
$Institute = $_POST['Institute'];
$Course = $_POST['Course'];
/* $fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname']; */
$image = $_FILES['image'];
$Exp_Work =$_POST['Exp_Work'];
//ERROR END HERE


$Matric = mysql_real_escape_string($Matric);
$Name = mysql_real_escape_string($Name);
$IC = mysql_real_escape_string($IC);
$Address = mysql_real_escape_string($Address);
$Tel = mysql_real_escape_string($Tel);
$Phone = mysql_real_escape_string($Phone);
$Email = mysql_real_escape_string($Email);
$Phone_Ref = mysql_real_escape_string($Phone_Ref);
/* $Total_sales = addslashes($_POST['Total_sales']);
$Date = addslashes($_POST['Date']); */
/* $Cer_name = mysql_real_escape_string($Cer_name); */
$Institute = mysql_real_escape_string($Institute);
$Course = mysql_real_escape_string($Course);
/* $Cat_name = addslashes($_POST['Cat_name']);
$Product_name = addslashes($_POST['Product_name']); */
/* $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($fname);
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($lname); */
$image['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($image['name']);
$Exp_Work = mysql_real_escape_string($Exp_Work);


$TARGET_PATH .= $image['name'];


if ( $Matric == "" ||$Name == "" ||$IC == "" ||$Address == "" ||$Tel == "" ||$Phone == "" ||$Email == "" ||$Phone_Ref == "" || $Institute == "" || $Course == ""|| $image['name'] == ""|| $Exp_Work == "" )
{
$_SESSION['error'] = "All fields are required";
echo "All fields are required";
exit;
}


if (!is_valid_type($image))
{
$_SESSION['error'] = "You must upload a jpeg, gif, or bmp";
echo"You must upload a jpeg, gif, or bmp";
exit;
}


if (file_exists($TARGET_PATH))
{
$_SESSION['error'] = "A file with that name already exists";
echo"A file with same name exists already";
exit;
}


if (move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $TARGET_PATH))
{

$sql = "insert into participant (Matric, Name, IC, Address, Tel, Phone, Email, Phone_Ref, Institute, Course, image, Exp_Work) values ('$Matric','$Name','$IC','$Address','$Tel','$Phone','$Email','$Phone_Ref','$Institute', '$Course','" . $image['name'] . "','$Exp_Work')";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error());
echo"Imgage uploaded successfully";
exit;
}
else
{

$_SESSION['error'] = "Could not upload file. Check read/write persmissions on the directory";
header("Location: fail.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Rahman. Is you problem in uploading the image without submiting the form with it, or do you need to know how to save the image to database and display it back to user while they are still editing the rest of the form? (or both?)

Comment: Hi Martina. the problem is in uploading image without submitting the form. Then, i try to think , save the image in db while user keep fill the form (from tutorial that i found). Which 1 is better?

Comment: Rahman, i just looked at that link you sent, it looks that the demo they have on that page is EXACLY what you want?! the only thing that it doesn't do is saving the submited picture into a database. Try to add another FORM (second one) on the same page with the form that sends the image where you can be filling another things. as to saving to database, search for **how to save image to mysql database in php** i'm sure there is plenty tutorials around

Comment: Nice. i found the correct tutorial.. tq Martini

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correctly what you want is to insert image into (probably MYSQL) database.

You could achieve this by using `base64_encode()` of image binary data and insert resulting plaintext in database.

```
$image = 'path/to/image/image.png';
$imagefordbs  =  base64_encode($image);
/*now your image is ready to be stored in database*/
```

However, this method has downsides since base64_encode() takes up about 33% more then original memory, some time to process input binary, and there is dedicated datatype for this kind of requirements in mysql - [BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html).

Comment: I would dare to dispute this idea. You do not need to base64_encode your image data when storing it to MySQL database. That's where BLOB fields have their name from (Binary Large OBject) - to store binary data(such as images). By base64_encode ing it, you would only make size of the data larger.

Comment: @Martinam you're totally right here,  it's my bad old habit to base64 every binary that needs to be transported or stored safely...

Answer (score 0):

As I read your question, you want to upload the image already using the tutorial / code you found and then submit the form separately when the image already has been uploaded.

To know where you can find your image after the file upload, you have two options:

1. Have the image upload return the file path when the upload is complete and include that variable in your form (as a hidden input for example);
2. Store the image path in a session variable so that when you submit the data fields, you can access that variable to get the information of the image.

**Edit:** You need to check the documentation of the Form Plugin for more details, but you can return something from your upload php script. You could for example `echo` the file name and then you would have it available in your `success` function:

```
    function afterSuccess(return_value)  {
        console.log(return_value);  // here you have what was echoed out by php

        $('#UploadForm').resetForm();  // reset form
        $('#SubmitButton').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable submit button
    }
```

Comment: i prefer no 1. but i cannot find how  to do it. if you can give me code example it will be clear.